# How to blur parent window when child window pops up in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I want to implement this functionality on my WPF app. I want there to be like a darkened overlay/background to the entire screen(parent window) where the pop up window (child window) occurs so it will give the pop up window(child window) more visibility Just like the Image below. It is a browser popup window. Then when the pop up window(child window) is closed,the darkened overlay/background s removed.[image]

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. `Window darkwindow = new Window()
                {
                    Background = Brushes.Black,
                    Opacity = 0.8,
                    AllowsTransparency = true,
                    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized,
                    Topmost = true
                };
                darkwindow.Show();

                un.ShowDialog();
                 darkwindow.Close();`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487729/gray-main-window-when-open-modal-dialog-in-wpf

Answer (score 4):

Prior to launching your dialog, modify the Effect property of the parent window:

```
parentWindow.Effect = new BlurEffect();
```

When the dialog closes:

```
parentWindow.Effect = null;
```

For adding color to the overlay, you could work in layers (for simplicity, I am going the code-behind method; go MVVM/behavior if you have the time):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label>Label</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Click</Button>
    </Grid>
    <Border x:Name="Splash" Grid.RowSpan="4" Opacity=".2" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Black">
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid.Effect = new BlurEffect();
            Splash.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            var dlg = new Window();

            dlg.ShowDialog();

            Splash.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Grid.Effect = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. is there a way i can add color to the blur?. cos it just blurs the element.

Comment: Updated sample to show colored layering.